# How to sort child divs in parents div based on data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to sort child `div`s inside a parent div using jQuery however my code is not working at all. My intention is to sort the child `div` elements in ascending order. Currently, my template structure is:

I am using this function to sort the child `div`s based on `data-year` attribute:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.year').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#parent').find('.child').sort(function(a, b) {
      var contentA = parseInt($(a).attr('data-year'));
      var contentB = parseInt($(b).attr('data-year'));
      return (contentA > contentB) ? -1 : (contentA < contentB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo('#parent');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="d_li" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Sort By
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu mt-1" aria-labelledby="d_li">
    <button class="small dropdown-item newest" type="button">Newest</button>
    <button class="small dropdown-item name">Name</button>
    <button class="small dropdown-item year" type="button">Year</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" data-year="2010" data-ins="2">year 2010, ins 2</div>
  <div class="child" data-year="2000" data-ins="3">year 2000, ins 3</div>
  <div class="child" data-year="2020" data-ins="1">year 2020, ins 1</div>
</div>
```

After clicking on <kbd>year</kbd> button nothing changes, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the operators `>` and `<` in sort function.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.year').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#parent').find('.child').sort(function(a, b) {
      var contentA = parseInt($(a).attr('data-year'));
      var contentB = parseInt($(b).attr('data-year'));
      return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo('#parent');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="d_li" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Sort By
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu mt-1" aria-labelledby="d_li">
    <button class="small dropdown-item newest" type="button">Newest</button>
    <button class="small dropdown-item name">Name</button>
    <button class="small dropdown-item year" type="button">Year</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" data-year="2010" data-ins="2">year 2010, ins 2</div>
  <div class="child" data-year="2000" data-ins="3">year 2000, ins 3</div>
  <div class="child" data-year="2020" data-ins="1">year 2020, ins 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, **if you look at [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) documentation. You can find out there is no need for ternary, less or greater than operation or whatever**. If you looking for sorting an array (or in your particular case array-like element like *HTML collection*) you should always consider these two statements:

> If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns less than `0`, sort `a` to an index lower than `b` (i.e. `a` comes first).
>
> If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns greater than `0`, sort `b` to an index lower than `a` (i.e. `b` comes first).

**NOTE:** The `compareFunction` in your case is `function(a, b){...}`.

**So you just need to stick with the first statement and subtract `b` from `a` that's all.**

Then your final code should be something like this:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.year').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#parent').find('.child').sort(function(a, b) {
      var contentA = parseInt($(a).attr('data-year'));
      var contentB = parseInt($(b).attr('data-year'));
      return contentA - contentB
    }).appendTo('#parent');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="d_li" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Sort By
          </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu mt-1" aria-labelledby="d_li">
    <button class="small dropdown-item newest" type="button">Newest</button>
    <button class="small dropdown-item name">Name</button>
    <button class="small dropdown-item year" type="button">Year</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" data-year="2010" data-ins="2">year 2010, ins 2</div>
  <div class="child" data-year="2000" data-ins="3">year 2000, ins 3</div>
  <div class="child" data-year="2020" data-ins="1">year 2020, ins 1</div>
</div>
```